# Is it yet possible to have different axis breaks / limits for individual facets in ggplot with free scale?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I saw that this related question was asked in 2010 (titled: [How do you set different scale limits for different facets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276218/how-do-you-set-different-scale-limits-for-different-facets)) and would like to know if it is yet possible to have different breaks for different facets?

The reason being is that I want only integer values in the lower chart (with breaks of 50 for the top chart) of following plot:
[image]

Code to reproduce the image:

```
dat <- data.frame(date=seq(0, 729, 1), Var1=round(seq(from=0, length.out=730, by=0.2)),   Var2=round(seq(from=5, length.out=730, by=0.01))  )
dat.m <- melt(dat, id.var="date")
ggplot(dat.m, aes(date,  value)) + 
      scale_x_continuous(name="Time") + 
      expand_limits(y=0) +
      ylab("Variable") + 
      geom_step() + 
      facet_grid(variable~., scales="free_y")+ 
      scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 150, by = 1))
```

Comment: I don't believe so. As far as I know, the reason may be a mix of philosophical and technical hurdles.

Comment: Until then, `gridExtra:::grid.arrange`. :)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback - when/if I get time I will try grid.arrange (for now I will leave the decimals)

Answer (score 1):

First, your code doesn't produce the same plot as on my machine. Can you provide the `sessionInfo()`?

I don't think it is possible. Best approximation of your request I could achieve in a simple way:

```
ggplot(dat.m, aes(date,  value)) + 
      scale_x_continuous(name="Time") + 
      expand_limits(y=0) +
      ylab("Variable") + 
      geom_step() + 
      facet_grid(variable~., scales="free_y")+ 
      scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(seq(0, 12, by = 2),seq(0, 150, by = 50)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that idea - I will leave as is for now.