# How to manage the free scaling in facet_wrap as the plot area size crops the labels on geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I have this code as given below

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x = -Ord, y = Value, fill = Item)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = comma) +
  facet_wrap(~Area, scales = "free", drop = T, nrow = 2) +
  labs(title = "Major Crops of South Asia, Top 10 on avg of 2006-2015",
       caption = "Source: fao.org") +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        plot.caption = element_text(face = "italic")) +
  geom_text(aes(label=Item), angle = 65,
            vjust=.3, hjust = -.1, size=3)
```

The image it produces is given as below
[image]
as you can see the bar labels are getting cropped. The problem with free scales in facet_wrap is that I cannot use `limits` in `scale_y_continuous` otherwise some plot areas would be blank due to wide variation in value range for each country.
So, my query is how to manage adding some extra space by increasing y scale for each plot freely without compromising the `scales`.

I have tried `scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, max(df1$Value)), labels = comma)` but then it kills `scales = "free"` in `facet_wrap`.
And, also the `max` values are to be groupwise in order to be really effective. This part I am unable to sort out.

I have deliberately avoided dput data just in case if it is needed kindly let me know. I would supply it.
Thanks.

Comment: can this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59270544/change-the-y-axis-limits-in-a-ggplot-of-multiple-plots (set breaks rather than limits)

Comment: You could try to increase the "expansion" of the scale, e.g. `scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(.05, .1))` will increase the default expansion (= 5 percent) to 10 percent at the upper end.

Comment: thanks! this was a wonderful suggestions. I just modified the `upper end` to `.2` and it yielded nicely.