# How to specify different scales format for different facets?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the following code, I am able to set two different scales for two facets. Now, I want to format the big scale (e.g. turn it into dollar with `scale_y_continuous(labels = dollar)`). How do I format individual facet's scale?

```
df <- data.frame(value = c(50000, 100000, 4, 3),
                 variable = c("big", "big", "small", "small"),    
                 x = c(2010, 2011, 2010, 2011))
ggplot(df) + geom_line(aes(x, value)) + facet_wrap(~ variable, scales = "free_y")
```

[A similar question a long time ago about setting individual limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276218/how-do-you-set-different-scale-limits-for-different-facets) has no answer. I was hoping that ggplot2 2.0 has done something about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `scale_y_continuous` allows for functions to be used for the `labels` argument. We can create a custom labeler that uses the minimum `big` value (or any other) as a threshold.

```
dollar <- function(x) {
  ifelse(x >= min(df$value[df$variable == "big"]),
    paste0("$", prettyNum(x, big.mark=",")), x)
}

ggplot(df) + geom_line(aes(x, value)) + facet_wrap(~ variable, scales = "free_y") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = dollar)
```

[image]

Comment: Very clever, though localized to my example in which the `big` and `small` values are separable. I suppose this means there is no way to tell ggplot2 I want `labeller1` for this facet, and `labeller2` for that facet?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.