# Different scale for faceted plots: scale_y_continuous()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a population pyramid, faceted across a number of regions. The problem is these regions have very different populations sizes, creating problems for the scale on the y axis (coord flipped).

I am trying to follow the method described here: https://rpubs.com/walkerke/pyramids_ggplot2 - which makes the pyramid by using negative numbers for one sex and then uses `scale_y_continuous()` to get rid of the negative numbers.

First i create a simple sample dataset, for 2 age groups, across two countries:

```
country <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2)
age.range <- c("0-4", "0-4", "5-9", "5-9", "0-4", "0-4", "5-9", "5-9")
sex <- rep(c("M", "F"), times = 4)
pop <- c(-8, 9, -9, 8, -88, 99, -99, 88)
pop.pyr <- data.frame(country, age.range, sex, pop)

pop.pyr

  country age.range sex pop
1       1       0-4   M  -8
2       1       0-4   F   9
3       1       5-9   M  -9
4       1       5-9   F   8
5       2       0-4   M -88
6       2       0-4   F  99
7       2       5-9   M -99
8       2       5-9   F  88
```

I can build the population pyramid and facet by country:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(pop.pyr, aes(x = age.range, y = pop, fill = sex)) + 
  geom_col(data = subset(pop.pyr, sex == "M")) +
  geom_col(data = subset(pop.pyr, sex == "F")) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(~ country, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

To fix the negative numbers on the y-scale (`coord_flip()`), i need to use: `scale_y_continuous()`; but doing so means i have to pick a `scale_y_continuous()` for both facets, which doesn't work.

```
ggplot(pop.pyr, aes(x = age.range, y = pop, fill = sex)) + 
  geom_col(data = subset(pop.pyr, sex == "M")) +
  geom_col(data = subset(pop.pyr, sex == "F")) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(~ country, scales = "free_x") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-100, 100, 20), labels = abs(seq(-100, 100, 20)))
```

[image]

The only way around this is to use a small variable for `by` in `seq` e.g. `scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-100, 100, 2), labels = abs(seq(-100, 100, 2)))`. Doing so however makes the larger scale a mess.

Is there a way to set `scale_y_continuous()` in such a way that I can have a different scale in different facets, while keeping: `scales = free_x`. Otherwise is there another way to get rid of the negative numbers in the pyramid using something other than `scale_y_continuous()`.

If not, is the only way to do this to develop each image separately and then `ggarrange()` or `cowplot()` - essentially manually faceting?

EDIT:

I tried using `facetscales()` as per the comments, but i couldn't get it to work the way i wanted, nor could i fully understand the man file.

Using the instructions from here: https://github.com/zeehio/facetscales; I installed and loaded the package

```
library(facetscales)
```

Then i create the list of scales:

```
scales.pyr <- list(`1` = scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-10, 10, 2), labels = abs(seq(-10, 10, 2))), `2` = scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-100, 100, 20), labels = abs(seq(-100, 100, 20))))
```

Update ggplot:

```
ggplot(pop.pyr, aes(x = age.range, y = pop, fill = sex)) + 
  geom_col(data = subset(pop.pyr, sex == "M")) +
  geom_col(data = subset(pop.pyr, sex == "F")) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_grid_sc(rows= vars(country), scales = list(y = scales.pyr))
```

[image]

This is clearly not right. The man file (https://github.com/zeehio/facetscales/blob/master/man/facet_grid_sc.Rd) says that i can use cols:

> facet_grid_sc(rows = NULL, cols = NULL, scales = "fixed",   space =
>   "fixed", shrink = TRUE, labeller = "label_value",   as.table = TRUE,
>   switch = NULL, drop = TRUE, margins = FALSE, facets = NULL)
>   ...
>   \item{cols}{A set of variables or expressions quoted by
>   \code{\link[=vars]{vars()}} and defining faceting groups on the rows
>   or columns dimension. The variables can be named (the names are passed
>   to \code{labeller}).

If i try cols:

```
ggplot(pop.pyr, aes(x = age.range, y = pop, fill = sex)) + 
geom_col(data = subset(pop.pyr, sex == "M")) +
geom_col(data = subset(pop.pyr, sex == "F")) +
coord_flip() +
facet_grid_sc(cols= vars(country), scales = list(y = scales.pyr))
```

I get:

```
Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : 
  attempt to select less than one element in get1index
```

As is also clear, the scales are fixed, the man page likewise says i can use `scales = "free"` or depreciated `"free_x"`.

> \item{scales}{A list of two elements (`x` and `y`). Each element can
>   be either `"fixed"` (scale limits shared across facets), `"free"`
>   (with varying limits per facet), or  a named list, with a different
>   scale for each facet value. Previous scale values (`"fixed"`,
>   `"free_x"`, `"free_y"`, `"free"` are accepted but soft-deprecated).}

But the code example requires the `scales` parameter to be filled with the list of scales.

Finally, i would really like to have six regions in two rows of three. The man page indicates that i can use rows and cols to facet different variables, but i can't see any references to `nrow()`, `ncol()`, for a single variable. Using them in a larger example gives:  `unused argument (ncol = 3)`.

Comment: Take a look at the `facetscales` package: https://github.com/zeehio/facetscales

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you set different scale limits for different facets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276218/how-do-you-set-different-scale-limits-for-different-facets)

Comment: Does `scale_y_continuous(labels = abs)` work for you? You don't have to specify the breaks explicitly that way.

Comment: Also, you don't need two `geom_col` layers with subsetted data sources. The link you referenced was referencing [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680075/simpler-population-pyramid-in-ggplot2), where the conversion to negative numbers was done in the second geom layer. Since yours is already negative, splitting into two has no additional benefit.

Comment: Thanks @Z.Lin that works: `scale_y_continuous(labels = abs)` sorts things out. Also, you are right no need for the two geom_col() calls. Solution provided below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is simple: use `scale_y_continuous(labels = abs)`. Final code looks as follows:

```
country <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2)
age.range <- c("0-4", "0-4", "5-9", "5-9", "0-4", "0-4", "5-9", "5-9")
sex <- rep(c("M", "F"), times = 4)
pop <- c(-8, 9, -9, 8, -88, 99, -99, 88)
pop.pyr <- data.frame(country, age.range, sex, pop)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(pop.pyr, aes(x = age.range, y = pop, fill = sex)) + 
geom_col() +
coord_flip() +
scale_y_continuous(labels = abs)
facet_wrap(~ country, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

That was a long way around. Thanks @Z.Lin.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is now possible using `facetted_pos_scales()` in the `ggh4x` library (https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/reference/facetted_pos_scales.html)

Comment: Provide an example of how to use it please!